Remove Border Bottom From MUI Selected Tabs - React
I am trying to custom style MUI Tabs  in order to get something like

I have create sample code Here is the codesandbox example in which border bottom will be 100% and for selected tab it should remove border bottom and add top, left and right border. I am not really concern about box shadow
Thanks in advance

.MuiButtonBase-root { bottom: -1px; z-index: 1; position: relative; }

.MuiTabs-root, .MuiTabs-scroller { overflow: visible !important; }

.MuiButtonBase-root.Mui-selected { background-color: #fff; }

Codesandbox playground
